# How to export data with path id of each path in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have created a graph with 3 paths as below.

```
Data
a,b
b,c
d,e
f,e
g,h
```

```
Graph
a->b->c
d->e<-f
g->h
```

Requirement:
How to export data as csv with unique path id of each node.

```
a,123
b,123
c,123
d,456
e,456
f,456
g,789
h,789
```

Note: I have 50 Million nodes in my graph.

Comment: How long is the longest path? Will you ever need to do anything with it? Can the path identifier be anything at all (i.e. do you care if it's a number, or a string or whatever)

Comment: How long is the longest path?
**It would be around 200-250 nodes**
 Will you ever need to do anything with it?
**I just need to upload the csv file into RDMS.**
Can the path identifier be anything at all (i.e. do you care if it's a number, or a string or whatever)
**Doesn't matter for me, any kind of unique identifier.**